# Finite map of local rings $R \to A$ with $R$ a DVR. When is target $A$ a DVR, too?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be discrete valuation ring with field of fractions $K$, and $\phi:R \to A$ a *finite, local* (i.e., $A$ dominates $R$ in the sense that its maximal ideal contains the image of maximal ideal of $R$) map of local rings.

**#Edit:** As Giorgio Genovesi pointed out, essentially the "interesting" case appear where $\phi$ is assumed to be in addition injective, i.e., $R$ as subring of $A$. Let's do this in the following.

**Question:** What are the weakest conditions to assure that $A$ is already discrete valuation ring too?

Clearly, $A$ have neccessarily to be a domain, therefore we can form the field of fractions $L:=\text{Frac}(A)$, which as Hagen Knaf in comments below explained not neccessarily imply that $B$, the *integral closure* of $R$ in $L$ - which is a dvr and which contains $A$ by construction due to finiteness of $A$ over $R$ - is finite itself over $R$.

So we could reformulate the question approaching it "from other side" (...hope that it not warps to strongly the flavour of initially posed question) by asking about proper intermediate rings $ R \subset A \subset B_L$ where $B_L$ is integral closure of $R$ inside a finite field extension $L/K$ with $A$ finite over $R$ (...as remarked this is a void condition if $A \subset B$ is already finite, eg in case $L/K$ separable)

Following discussion with Hagen Knaf there some criteria (eg via the conductor) to decide if a concrete such intermediate ring  $ R \subset A \subset B_L$ is already $B_L$.
But my primary concern can be phrased to be focused on **existence statement** of such intermediate rings. If we have for fixed finite extension $L/K$ such intermediate rings. It should be intuitively expected that there exist almost always a plethora of those. But are the exceptions?

Let me also state two boring cases:
**(1)** $L =K$, then $B=R$, so $A=R$, as $A$ dominates $R$, and
**(2)** $A=R[T]/F(T)$, with $F(T)\in R[T]$ Eisenstein polynomial (then, the maximal ideal of $A$ is generated by $t:=\overline{T}$, the image of $T$ wrt canonical map $R[T] \to R[T]/F(T)=A$).

Comment: Since DVRs are dimension $1$ the only quotients that are domains are the trivial quotient and the residue field. Since $A$ needs to be a domain you have $\phi$ will have kernel that is either the maximal ideal or the 0 ideal. So you may consider the cases in which $A$ is a $K$ algebra or $R$ is a subring of $A$.

Comment: @GiorgioGenovesi: Yes, thanks to elaborating this point. The "interesting" things are expected to happen in last case where $R$ is assumed to be subring of $A$. So it's reasonable to focus the question on this case only.

Comment: I am sceptical with regard to an answer to your question: there are finite, inseparable extensions $L|K$ such that the integral closure $B$ of $R$ in $L$ is not finitely generated. If one focuses on purely inseparable extensions, then $B$ is automatically a DVR and any (finitely) generated subring $A\subseteq B$, $R\subseteq A$ is a local extension of $R$. Among them there are many having fraction field $L$. We would need a condition that disqualifies them all as candidates for being integrally closed.

Comment: @HagenKnaf: Thank you, the issue depending on (in)separability of $L/K$ I missed. So far I know if the latter is separable, then $R \to B$ is finite, but as you said for pure inseparable ext that's not garanteed (...do you know an example?)

Comment: The point of my concern is that I want to insist on finiteness of $R \to A$. So for $L/K$ separable I'm interested in all intermediate rings $R \subset A \subset B$ with $\text{Frac}(A)=L$ but $A \neq B$. (Do such exist?) For  $L/K$ purely inseparable in turn only those $A$ with $R \to A$ finite. Is there something interesting known about such rings? Eg if we regard firstly"separable" case - where I expect less "pathologies -  do such intermediate rings exist?

Comment: @HagenKnaf: Concerning the condition disqualifying $A$ from beeing integrally closed, what about $\dim_{A/m_A} m_A/m_A^2$? It's $1$ iff max ideal $m_A$ generated by one element due Nakayama lemma. Is $A$ assumed to be a domain, the it would be dvr, right?

Comment: Another one, what about  [conductor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_(ring_theory))?Looks nearly tailor made for the point you coined in your last sentence

Comment: But these two criteria help if we already have fetched a concrete intermediate ring $R \subset A \subset B$. Is there a criterion to decide **if there exist** such proper intermediate ring $A$ with $\text{Frac}(A)=L=\text{Frac}(B)$, which is finite over $A$ (...the latter condition is clearly void if $A\to B$ is finite, eg $L/K$ separable). And furthermore it's possible to "measure" (finite # vs infinite) how many such intermediate rings should apear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to the original question but to the question on the existence of intermediate rings $A$ posted in a comment: Assume that $L/K$ is separable and that the DVR $B$ is the integral closure of $R$. Let $\theta$ be a primitive element of $L/K$. Since for every $x\in L$ either $x$ or $x^{-1}$ are in $B$ we can assume $\theta\in B$. Now either $\theta\in B^\times$ or $\theta+1\in B^\times$. Since $\theta+1$ is a primitive element too, we have shown that there always exists a unit of $B$ which is a primitive element of $L/K$.

Case 1: Assume that the extension of residue fields $B/m_B\supset R/m_R$ is proper. Then for every $s\in m_B$ we have $R[s\theta]\neq B$ sincs otherweise $R[s\theta]/m_B=R/m_A$. Obviously $L=\mathrm{Frac}(R[s\theta])$.

Case 2: Assume that $m_RB\neq m_B$. Let $m_B=tB$; then $m_RB=t^{e}B$ for some $e>1$. Then for every $k\geq e$ we have $R[t^k\theta]\neq B$. Otherwise

$
t=r_0+r_1(t^k\theta)+\ldots +r_n(t^k\theta)^n
$

for some $r_i\in R$. Consequently $r_0\neq 0$ since the remaining part of the sum is divisible by $t^e$. However $r_0$ either is a unit in $R$ or is divisible by $t^e$. Both cases lead to a contradiction.

Comment: I'm wondering to which ammount your analysis of the case with $L/K$ separable can be extended to the case where $L/K$ not neccessarily separated, but $L$ is generated over $K$ by a single element - let it call also $\theta$ - which with same argumentation as in your answer can be assumed to lie in $ B^\times$.

Comment: Let's see, the Case $1$ with proper extension of residue field $B/m_B\supset R/m_R$, should go through exactly in same way (...even for arbitrary finite extensions $L/K$) resulting in giving us therefore a plethora of explicitly constructed proper intermediate rings $A$. The Case 2, so with identical resudue fields $B/m_B =R/m_R$, is so far I see a bit more subtle. 
Let $m_B=t_B \cdot B$ and  $m_R=t_R \cdot R$. If  $m_RB\neq m_B$, your argumentation so far I see goes also through and gives us again explicitly constructed proper intermediate rings.

Comment: But what about if $m_RB = m_B$ in Case 2, ie with identical residue fields. If I'm not missing something, then in case $L/K$ separable you analyzed it should then follow $B=A$ by Nakayama, so here we substantially need that $B$ is **finite** over $A$, otherwise we cannot apply Nakayama.

So two central questions arise in this context:

Comment: : **(1):** Can it be concluded in case  $m_RB = m_B$ and $B/m_B =R/m_R$ that $B=A$ in more weaker situations, when $B$ not neccessarily assumed a priori to be finite over $A$. Do you know a counterexample with $B \neq A$ even thought the two consitions on max ideals and residue fields are satisfied?

Comment: and **(2):** Are there conterexamples where $L/K$ is generated by **single element**, ie $L=K(\theta)$, but the integral closure $B$ of $A$ in $L$ is not finite? As you remarked, for general finite $L/K$ (eg purely inseparable with $L$ cannot be generated by a single element) such $B$ exist, but what if we restrict to the situation where $L$ is generated by only one element?

Do you know if these two questions have positive answers?

Comment: NB: So if my considerations are reasonable the most difficult case to understand the intermediate rings $R\subset A \subset B $ in this context is where $B/A$ is not finite even though $L/K$ is (...so no Nakayama for $A\subset B$ available),  but where the residues $B/m_B= R/m_R$ coinside and no "ramification" happens , ie$m_RB =m_B$. In number theory there is a well known identity $[L:K]=[B/m_B:R/m_R] \cdot e$, but clearly this is only for number fields, so separable, in general that's only an inequality

Comment: Concerning the "plethora of intermediate rings" one should be careful: the rings appearing as examples could be equal for different $s$ respectively $k$.

Comment: It is well-known that the finiteness of $R\rightarrow B$ is equivalent to the equality $[L:K]=e[B/m_B:R/m_R]$. Therefore the case $[L:K]>e[B/m_B:R/m_R]$ never appears if $L/K$ is separable.

Comment: Yes, "plethora of intermediate rings" was indeed a wrong description. Let me say your argumentation presents a way to give give explicitly "a plethora of generators" which gives proper intermediate rings, which of course could give identical rings for different generators, so it's indeed a constructive **existence statement**, but which not capturing additionally a kind of "measure" for amount of such intermediate rings.

Comment: Alright, so this equivalence that $R \to B$ finite iff $[L:K]=e[B/m_B:R/m_R]$ (... by the way, do your know ad hoc a reference for a proof of this statement?), answers *sharply(!)* when $m_RB = m_B$ and $B/m_B =R/m_R$ is equivalent to $R=B$ , ie question **(1)** from my recent comments.

Comment: Moreover, it turns finding a counterexample in question **(2)** into finding a finite extension $K \subset L = K(\theta)$ *generated by a single element* such that $[L:K]>e[B/m_B:R/m_R]$. Do you know how to construct such one? Looks that one could try something over $K:=\mathbb{F}_q((t))$, but haven't figured out yet ...